# I need to build a planner app, does one language have open source advantages?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, web-development, django, ruby-on-rails

I want to build an application for group leaders to make individual schedules for their group members. I imagine there must be an open source project that already has most of these features/abilities. Or, several projects that can be hacked together.

Features it needs:

- Nested account creation (leader creates accounts for members)
- Calendar View (leader can view all group member schedules)
- Planner View (list of everything leader/member needs to do and when)
- Lesson plans (assignments and notes)
- Duplicate lessons/lesson templates
- Facebook logins for leaders and members
- Ability to import/view Google Calendar

**Question**:

1. Is there an open source project that already has most of these
   features?

Comment: Where does language come into this?

Comment: @Mawg because I was hoping one might have libraries or open-source projects that would take care of some of the development.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should have a look at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org) (a CMS).

If you would combine it with contributed modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) and [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) you have most of the features you're looking for. From then on it would only be a matter of configuring it all to make it a perfect fit for your needs.